# Find all $x$ in the interval without a graphing calculator

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Find all $x$ in in the interval $[0, 2π]$ that satisfy the equation:

$$4\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(2x) + 5\sin^2(x) = 4.$$

I found the solution with a graphing calculator but I need the way of finding it without one. I have tried everything I could think of in the past 2 days but I'm still stuck.

I have tried things like:\begin{align*}
 \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1\\
\sin(2x) = 2 \times \sin(x)\times \cos(x)
\end{align*}
which in my place will be:$$
\sin^2(2x) = 4 \times \sin^2(x) \times \cos^2(x).
$$

But after using one of them I get stuck a bit later.

The answer using graphing calculator is: $0, π/3, 2π/3, π, 4π/3, 5π/3, 2π$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the trig identity to replace $\sin(2x)$ with $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$. You will now have an equation with $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$.

Now use the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ to get an equation with only $\sin^2(x)$ or only with $\cos^2(x)$. It will be a quadratic equation in that expression. (Hint: the quadratic equation will be a little easier to solve if you convert everything to $\sin^2(x)$.)

Solve that quadratic equation, then find $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ (depending on what you chose in the previous step), then find $x$.

So you had the right identities but apparently did not see just where to use them. You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: last time I stopped at `cos^2(x) = 1/4`.
now `x = pi/3`. Does this automatically mean to use every `n*pi/3` to get the answer I found with the graphics calculator?

Comment: If you converted everything to $\cos^2(x)$ (which I did not recommend) you do get $\cos^2(x)=\frac 14$. That means $\cos(x)=\frac 12$ or $\cos(x)=-\frac 12$. Each of those has *two* solutions in the domain $[0,2\pi]$. Can you see them both? But you left out another possibility for $\cos^2(x)$ other than $\frac 14$. Can you see it?

Comment: I'm seeing the 1/2 and -1/2 but not the other possibility.
I can't even see how to choose `sin^2(x)` instead of `cos^2(x)` because I end up with `4cos^2(x) + 5sin^2(x) = 4 + 4 sin^2(x) cos^2(x)` which led to `sin^2(x) = 4 sin^2(x) cos^2(x)`

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas: In that last equation of yours, replace $\cos^2(x)$ with $1-\sin^2(x)$ and you end up with a simple equation using only $\sin^2(x)$. It is hard for me to guide you to the other possibility for $\cos^2(x)$ without you showing me the equation that got you to the $\frac 14$ possibility. Anyway, I am going to bed now. If you have more questions, I'll answer them in the morning.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. I'll try and work on the rest answers `{0, pi , 2pi}` how and why they're with the answers. Thank you so much